# How to send email to multiple addresses in range of cells that updates weekly?

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I am a novice at programming. I have setup a google spreadsheet that will send a weekly email reminder to those who have upcoming assignments. The spreadsheet automatically pulls the 4 email addresses of those who are assigned each week and places them in A1, B1, A2, B2 (i.e. A1:B2). I want the script to find the 4 email addresses (that change each week) and send the same email to all four of them.

When I hardcode the cc recipients into the MailApp line, it works fine. But because the recipients list changes weekly I want to reference the cells A1:B2 instead. When I try to do that, I get an Invalid Email error. The debugger shows that var ccrecipients is picking up the right cells, but I think the problem is that it returns it as an array instead of as a string. That's as far as I'm able to reason through it.

A few snippets of my code:

```
var ccrecipients = sheet.getRange('A1:B2').getValues();

MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, "", {htmlBody: message, cc: ccrecipients});
```

Thanks in advance for your help. I've relied heavily on these forums to put together the code that I have. I've always been able to find an answer, until this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your observation is almost correct, `sheet.getRange('A1:B2').getValues();` return an array of arrays, something like `[[A1,B1],[A2,B2]]` A & B representing the values in the cells to simplify my example.

And what you need in the end is a "flat" string with all the needed recipients separated by commas `"A1,B1,A2,B2"`.

The simplest way to do that is to flatten the whole thing,that will create a string with comma separations and that's exactly what we need.

```
sheet.getRange('A1:B2').getValues().toString();
```

That should do the trick ;-)

Comment: Serge, thanks for the quick reply! I put in the new code and I still got the invalid email error. The debugger shows the results like this now: ["email1@whatever.com", "email2@whatever.com", "email3@whatever.com, "email4@whatever.com"]. Any ideas?

Comment: Ooops, didn't see your comment completely... seems good to me... wait a second, I'll test further___ sorry, my mistake. code edited.

Comment: [13-12-03 16:19:30:283 EST] [email1@whatever.com, email2@whatever.com, email3@whatever.com, email4@whatever.com]

Comment: Sorry to be dense, I must have missed something. Your original reply appears unchanged. ??? At any rate, I recopied and pasted into my script and it still says Invalid Email.

Comment: my answer is modified, maybe try to refresh your Browser. code is sheet.getRange('A1:B2').getValues().toString();

Comment: Aaah, refreshed and saw the change. Plugged it in and it worked great! Thanks Serge! (I'm new to this forum stuff, is there somehow I can give you credit for solving this???)

Comment: simply accept the answer with the "phantom" V on the left. Thanks, that's it ;-)